# If a sequence diverges, then does its reciprocal go to 0 (as n approaches infinity)?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Take for example, $a_n = \frac{n!}{n^n}$, and it's reciprocal $\frac{1}{a_n} = \frac{n^n}{n!}$

Now, with this  $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^n}{n!}$ diverging to infinity, is it safe to say that the $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}$ is $0$?

Since they are reciprocal of each other and for this to be true: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{a_n} = \infty$, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n$ must be $0$.

I don't know if this way of thinking is totally flawed though. So thanks in advance for the responses.

Comment: It is true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1{a_n}=0$. This can be checked with the definitions.

Comment: $a_n = (-1)^n$ is a divergent sequence ...

Comment: @MartinR That might address the question in the title, but the question body does specify $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{a_n} = \infty$.

Comment: @Arthur: I am aware of that :) My comment was meant as a “nudge” to improve/clarify the question.